# How do i code the precise swip controls like in the mobile game "ALONE"

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to make my touch controls like in the game [ALONE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.laserdog.alone&hl=en). I managed to make a prototype Android game with the same controls but i was wondering how do i
maintain the same touch sensitivity across multiple device resolutions?
I noticed when i played my prototype game on high resolution devices
such as 1920 x1080 the touch sensitivity was too much compared to
lower resolutions like 480 x 800. here is my code:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        player.rotate(Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * delta);
    }
```

update method in player class:

```
public void update(float delta){
    x += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation)) * speed * delta;
}
```

I have this method in my player class

```
public void rotate(float x) {
    this.rotation -= x * 90.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale the input delta by the device DPI.

```
player.rotate(Gdx.input.getDeltaX() / Gdx.graphics.getPpiX() * DEGREES_PER_DEVICE_INCH);
```

Comment: I didn't have time to try this but i tried your solution today. is the DEGREES_PER_DEVICE_INCH the dpi?

Comment: That's how many degrees you want it to rotate per inches of finger movement. The DPI is from getPpiX().